# Redirect container remote calls to other host

Tags: docker, integration-testing, docker-compose

I want to test my app in docker isolated. I don't want to change app code for this. My app calls remote server (`www.example.com` e.g.). I want to mock this server (`www.example.com`). I want create my remote server mock container and run it with my app in `docker-compose`. In app remote urls are just constants.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is by making the hardcoded url's not hard coded. Then you can replace them with environment variables in your docker-compose file. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

However, since you do not want to make any changes to the application, perhaps you can make some changes in /etc/hosts file. Replace the ip-address of the old server with the new server. https://superuser.com/questions/601574/how-do-i-redirect-a-domain-to-another-domain-locally

Answer (score 0):

I guess creating your containers with docker-compose. Or linking containers using just docker. Not sure if this is needed anyway.

Then, just get into your web container, edit /etc/hosts and map example.com to your "other container" ip.

--

Tip:
You can get the ip of the container like this:

```
# get into
docker exec -it  CONTAINER_ID bash

# consult ip
root@2e23d01384ac:/# ip add | grep global
```

Or using any of these other methods:
http://networkstatic.net/10-examples-of-how-to-get-docker-container-ip-address/